# Dynamic formcontrol in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a preference screen where user signs up for various services, these services are received from a service.

My Json is something of this sort

```
[   {
      category : 'General',
      source :    [   { name: 'ABC News', url: 'abc-news-au', subscribed: false},
                      { name: 'Associated Press', url: 'associated-press', subscribed: false}],
      numberofarticles: 4
   },
 repeat above node multiple times 
]
```

So the service could send X different categories to which user can subscribe to. And in each category he could then select the news channel he want to subscribe.

I am building the preference screen and am a bit stuck on how to create the dynamic UI where all of this listed & user choice get transmitted to the server for update/save.

Using template driven approach its easy to create the form but sending value back is not working.

**Nice to have** - Also I am trying to find an approach where any update the user does directly gets saved to the json so that I dont have manually check each click the user did and update the json. For e.g. if user checked the 'ABC News' channel the subscribed option becomes True.

**Template Form**

```
form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <md-tab-group>
     <md-tab *ngFor="let news of newsList" label={‌{news.category}}>

       <h3 color="accent">Select news sources</h3>
       <md-select multiple placeholder="" ngModel name="{‌{news.source}}">
          <md-option *ngFor="let source of news.source" [value]="source.name">
             {‌{source.name}}
         </md-option>
       </md-select>
      <br>

      <h3>Number of new articles of each topic</h3>
      <md-slider ngModel #numberofArticles name="numberofArticles" min="1" max="5" step="1"
         value={‌{news.NoOfArticles}} tickInterval="auto" thumbLabel></md-slider>
      <br>

     </md-tab>
   </md-tab-group>
 <br>
 <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use ReactiveFormsModule instead of FormsModule where you can build the from dynamically in TS. You can read about [REACTIVE FORMS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html)

Comment: I did read thru Todd's article on how this can be done [link](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms#creating-a-dynamic-form) However I wanted to use material design. Will need to find out what is the best way to use Reactive Forms + Material design for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with template driven forms, reactive forms were not suited for my scenario. {If anyone find a way with reactive forms do let me know }

The html is more or less the same except I added index to have unique names

**Template Form**

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">

<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let news of newsList; let i=index"
            label={{news.category}}
            ngModelGroup={{news.category}}
            #{{news.category}}="ngModelGroup"
            >
      <h3 color="accent">Select news sources</h3>
        <br>
         <section class="example-section" ngModelGroup="news">
              <md-checkbox ngModel class="example-margin"
                           name={{news.category}}_{{x}}
                          *ngFor="let source of news.source; let x=index"
                           [(ngModel)]="source.subscribed">
                  {{source.name}}
              </md-checkbox>
          </section>

        <h3>Number of new articles of each topic</h3>
        <md-slider ngModel name="numberofArticles_{{i}}"
                  min="1" max="5" step="1"
                  value={{news.NoOfArticles}} tickInterval="auto"
                  thumbLabel>
        </md-slider>
        <br>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
  <br>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" >Save</button>
 </form>
```

With this each category I looped thru had a unique name for its node. Also I grouped element using ngModelGroup this helped a lot later.

**Component Code**

```
 onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
     // Check if form is dirty
      if (f.dirty) {
            const myControls = f.controls;
            let i = 0;
            // Update the user preferences based on what he selected on the ui. DefaultNews is my model data which is needs to be updated
            const defaultCategories = DefaultNews.defaultNews;

            defaultCategories.forEach(element => {
               // Check if the news category is dirty - i.e. each Tab on the UI
                if ((myControls[element.category]).dirty) {
                   // check if news websites were touched i.e. if any checkbox from the group is updated
                   if ((myControls[element.category].get('news')).dirty) {
                      let newsSubscription;
                      let index = 0;
                      // Read thru each news source and set it from the ui
                      element.source.forEach(newsSource => {
                             newsSubscription = (myControls[element.category].get('news')).get(element.category + '_' + index);
                             newsSource.subscribed = newsSubscription.value;
                             index = index + 1;
                      });
                   }
                   // check if the number of articles was touched - i.e. if slider was moved
                   if ((myControls[element.category].get('numberofArticles_' + i)).dirty) {
                     element.NoOfArticles = (myControls[element.category].get('numberofArticles_' + i)).value;
                   }

                   i = i + 1;
                }
            });
      }
  }
```

I checked if the form is dirty if yes then check a specific node is dirty if yes only then go and update user preference.

I have attached screenshot to give an idea what the preference screen is. I have kept it simple in terms of elements and zero styling to make it simpler to see the actual code.

[image: First Tab of Preferences screen]

[image: Second Tab of Preferences screen]